# can't update entire document in mongodb with c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm trying to update entire document in mongoDB, without changing the objectID but nothing works.

`newUser` is my model, with the `objectID` like in the collection.... but different details:

```
var filter = Builders<User>.Filter.Eq(u => u.UserID, newUser.UserID);
                UsersCollection.UpdateOne(filter, newUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

found the solution:

var documentToUpdate = UsersCollection.Find(u => u.UserID == newUser.UserID).**First();**
                documentToUpdate = newUser;
                UsersCollection.ReplaceOne(c => c.UserID == documentToUpdate.UserID, documentToUpdate);